# how to Check for file extension and accordingly open with the default program in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I tried using the following code but it parses through each if loop instead  of according to its file extension. I feel like my if statement isin't correct. Could anyone simplify the process? All I want is the file should open from the folder according to its default file extension program. I also need to project it on a monitor. So would also need to integrate the full screen mode code that I've added.

```
:loop         
cd c:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader
set dir1=folder location
for %%X IN ("%dir1%\*.*") DO ( 
taskkill /f /im "AcroRd32.exe"
taskkill /f /im "Powerpnt.exe"
taskkill /f /im "Winword.exe"
echo %%X
IF %%X EXIST "%dir1%\*.pdf" ( 
start /max AcroRd32.exe /A "pagemode=FullScreen" "%%X"
timeout /t 5
)
Else IF %%X EXIST "%dir1%\*.pptx" (
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Powerpnt.exe" /S "%%X"
 timeout /t 5
 )
 ELSE IF %%X EXIST "%dir1%\*.docx" (
 start /max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft  Office\root\Office16\Winword.exe"  "%%X"
 timeout /t 5
 )
 )
 goto loop
```

Comment: You aren't launching the default program associated with a file extension. If you do want to launch the default program, simply use `start "%%X"`.

Comment: @IInspectable it didn't work on just using the start "%%X" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
IF %%X EXIST "%dir1%\*.pdf" (
```

to

```
IF /i "%%~xX"==".pdf" (
```

(and follow the bouncing ball for the other extensions)

That is, if (case-insensitive) the extension of the filename found is equal to (keystring) then execute the specified command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The comparison of extension seems to be coming now. But it still ain't working like if else statement. its going through every loop. The error shows that Else is not an internal command.

Comment: The "else" keyword must be on the same physical line as the `)` preceding it and also the `(` following it.

Comment: Change `"%%~xX"` to `"%%~X"`.

Comment: @Liturgist: Not so. ~X gives the name+extension. ~xX gives just the extension.

Comment: `"*.docx"` should be `".docx"` `%%~xX` means `the extension of the filename in %%X` which is `.docx` not `*.docx`. Next problem may be the `)` in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. The `)` may be being interpreted as closing the block instead of being part of the command. You can "escape" characters that have a special meaning to batch by inserting a caret (`^`) before the character, so use `C:\Program Files (x86^)` for instance. Escaping with caret works for `)` `|` `<` `>` but not for `%` which needs `%` to escape it, eg `echo 100%% complete`.

Comment: @Magoo - Sorry, I forgot about the `x` extension switch.